# pm2 node api start seems to not respect host?

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I'm trying to wrap around `pm2`:

```js
pm2.start(
  {
    apps: [
      {
        script: 'app.js',
        path: 'remote/path',
        name: 'App',
        autorestart: false,
        host: [123.456.789],
        username: 'root',
      },
    ],
  },
  err => {
    if (err) throw err
  },
)
```

It still seems to be trying to run `app.js` on my local machine, and not the host `123.456.789` - any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

`host` should be an array of strings: `host: ['123.456.789']`.